# Is it possible to sum a series of numbers and altering each number?

Tags: excel

I need to get a sum of [1/1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...], but my data looks like [1,2,3,4...] is it possible to modify my initial data inside the `sum` function without creating another dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done. Assuming the data is in A1:A9. The formula would be

=SUM(1/A1:A9).

You have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after entering the formula, so that it appears in the formula bar inside curly brackets, like so

`{=SUM(1/A1:A9)}`

Comment: Great Answer! Sorry I missed the Ctrl-Shift-Enter key-combo needed. If you feel my edit to be unhelpful, please roll it back. :)